# What is difference is posting data via html form post and Ajax post?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have Post API like below. I am calling this via AJAX and I get request in user parameter but StreamReader comes as empty.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("getUserBankList")]
    public IHttpActionResult getUserBankList(UserProfile user)
    {
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
      string getUserBankList = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

I have another Post API like below. I am calling this via HTML form post but I get req parameter as empty but StreamReader is able to fetch posted data.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("getUserBankList")]
    public IHttpActionResult ValidateToken(ValidateRequest req)
    {
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
      string getUserBankList = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Could anybody please explain how in above two differnt post data is getting send.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return any thing form action after successfully execute your's action.

```
return Ok(getUserBankList);
```

Please add above line after getting the response in *reader.ReadToEnd()*